# Can the adverb ‘next’ be placed before its modified verb?

Tags: adverbs, modifiers, adjuncts

> South African track star Oscar Pistorius has been granted bail over
>   the murder of his girlfriend, Reeva Steenkamp. The decision was made
>   after a four-day hearing, with the magistrate ruling the prosecution
>   had not made a strong enough case that Pistorius would try to flee the
>   country. He’ll **next** face court on June the fourth. [(ABC News)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-02-23/abc-news/4535562)

Can the adverb ‘next’ be placed before its modified verb, face?

Comment: Obviously it *can*, since ABC News just used it that way. They couldn't have put it directly after *face* anyway - it has to either go where it is, or after *face **court***. No real difference - just a stylistic choice.

Comment: [Here are lots more examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+will+next%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), too.

Comment: Note that it is *next* which modifies, not the following verb; and the head of the verb phrase is *'ll*, not *face*

Comment: @StoneyB: Good point - so there's a *third* valid alternative position. *"He **next** will face court on June the fourth."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjuncts are often placed between an auxiliary and its lexical verb, especially if the adjunct is ‘light’ - consists of only a few words.

- I have *already* seen that movie.
- You should *really* make an effort to see that movie.
- He will *probably* see that movie tomorrow.
- We have *certainly* seen movies like this one before.
- You can *most conveniently* see that movie at the Roxy.

Adjuncts of place are rarely placed in this position. Heavier adjuncts and even subordinate clauses are permitted there; but these must be used with discretion or readers will lose their way:

- You may occasionally, from that place, under the right weather conditions, and if you have a sufficiently powerful telescope, see Jersey.

This sort of thing is a common vice in academic writing.